# WPF DataGrid removing NewItemPlaceholder on IEditableCollectionView.CancelNew()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

### Overview

I'm developing a WPF application (using .NET 4.5), part of which involves showing some data in a DataGrid.
The user has the ability to add a new row inside the DataGrid and delete one via a button elsewhere.

I have an issue when the user starts adding a new row that cannot be committed and then presses the delete button.
The new row should be canceled and the DataGrid reset to its previous state.
However, the DataGrid's `NewItemPlaceholder` row is deleted and never shown again.

I've made a [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81ocswt3qvojizd/WpfApplication3.zip?dl=0) that demonstrates the issue.
[Here](http://screencast.com/t/AecgzSflO) is a short screencast as well.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njobC.png) is what the sample app looks like.

To reproduce:

1. Double click the Price cell on the topmost row
2. Enter an invalid number to trigger validation via an exception
3. (optional) Select another row
4. Click the delete button

### Code

The viewmodel gets the data in an ObservableCollection, which is used as the source for a collection view.
I have a simple command wired to the delete button. If the user is adding an item (`IEditableCollectionView.IsAddingNew`) I try to cancel the operation using `.CancelNew()` on the collectionView. However, when the command completes the DataGrid has its `NewItemPlaceholder` deleted.

So far, I've tried:

- [Triggering the DataGrid](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,f05883b487182de0) to make the placeholder appear again by setting `dataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true`, which fixes the issue somewhat, but that's a horrible workaround and it's buggy, afterwards the placeholder is not editable.
- Removing the invalid item from the source collection: `this.productsObservable.Remove(this.Products.CurrentAddItem as Product)`.
  This doesn't change the behavior, the placeholder is still removed.
- Removing the item from the collection view: `this.Products.Remove(this.Products.CurrentAddItem)`.
  This throws an exception, which makes sense: `'Remove' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.`

**Is there another way I can cancel the user's add AND have the NewItemPlaceholder showing?**

In the sample project I'm instantiating the data inside the VM constructor for simplicity.
In reality I'm using async calls to a service, wrapping the result in ObservableCollection and the ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged. The business object doesn't implement INPC.

XAML for the sample project:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Content="Delete row" />
        <DataGrid
            ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            CanUserAddRows="True"
            SelectionMode="Single">
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel, together with a simple Business Object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<Product> productsObservable;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.productsObservable = new ObservableCollection<Product>()
            {
                new Product() { Name = "White chocolate", Price = 1},
                new Product() { Name = "Black chocolate", Price = 2},
                new Product() { Name = "Hot chocolate", Price = 3},
            };

            this.Products = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.productsObservable) as IEditableCollectionView;
            this.Products.NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;

            this.DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.OnDeleteCommandExecuted);
        }

        public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }
        public IEditableCollectionView Products { get; private set; }

        private void OnDeleteCommandExecuted()
        {
            if (this.Products.IsAddingNew)
            {
                this.Products.CancelNew();
            }
        }

    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?, because I have the same issue

Comment: @Jamaxack I switched to a Telerik RadGridView, as that was an option for me at the time. Also take a look at this, if it helps (I just don't remember if it was the same issue as this post, but I remember it was related): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1465806/listcollectionview-with-newitemplaceholderposition-atbeginning-doesnt-remove-last-element-but-the-one-before-it .

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
private void OnDeleteCommandExecuted()
{
    if (this.Products.IsAddingNew)
    {
        this.Products.CancelNew();
        this.Products.AddNew();
    }
}
```

You'll still delete the row with the bad input, but you'll add a new (mostly) empty row. The only problem, although I'm sure its fixable, is that you get the default `0` value in the numerical column not a `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this too. It looks ok (besides having to workaround the zero issue), but the problem is that the new row doesn't go into Edit Mode when you double-click it afterwards. Any idea why?

Comment: @Stanislav The problem is that after `_.CancelNew(); _.AddNew();`, the `NewItemPlaceHolder` is no longer the last row in the `DataGrid`. It still exists in the visual tree, but it's no longer visible.